# Building an event scheduling/custom cronjob system in PHP and MySQL, is this a sane approach?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have an application where I intend users to be able to add events at any time, that is, chunks of code that should only run at a specific time in the future determined by user input. Similar to cronjobs, except at any point there may be thousands of these events that need to be processed, each at its own specific due time. As far as I understand, crontab would not be able to handle them since it is not meant to have massive number of cronjobs, and additionally, I need precision to the second, and not the minute. I am aware it is possible to programmatically add cronjobs to crontab, but again, it would not be enough for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Also, I need these to be real time, faking them by simply checking if there are due items whenever the pages are visited is not a solution; they should also fire even if no pages are visited by their due time. I've been doing some research looking for a sane solution, I  read a bit about queue systems such as gearman and rabbitmq but a FIFO system would not work for me either (the order in which the events are added is irrelevant, since it's perfectly possible one adds an event to fire in 1 hour, and right after another that is supposed to trigger in 10 seconds)

So far the best solution that I found is to build a daemon, that is, a script that will run continuously checking for new events to fire. I'm aware PHP is the devil, leaks memory and whatnot, but I'm still hoping nonetheless that it is possible to have a php daemon running stably for weeks with occasional restarts, so as long as I spawn new independent processes to do the "heavy lifting", the actual processing of the events when they fire.

So anyway, the obvious questions:

1) Does this sound sane? Is there a better way that I may be missing?

2) Assuming I do implement the daemon idea, the code naturally needs to retrieve which events are due, here's the pseudocode of how it could look like:

```
while 1 {
    read event list and get only events that are due
    if there are due events
        for each event that is due 
            spawn a new php process and run it
            delete the event entry so that it is not run twice
    sleep(50ms)
}
```

If I were to store this list on a MySQL DB, and it certainly seems the best way, since I need to be able to query the list using something on the lines of "SELECT * FROM eventlist where duetime >= time();", is it crazy to have the daemon doing a SELECT every 50 or 100 milliseconds? Or I'm just being over paranoid, and the server should be able to handle it just fine? The amount of data retrieved in each iteration should be relatively small, perhaps a few hundred rows, I don't think it will amount for more than a few KBs of memory. Also the daemon and the MySQL server would run on the same machine.

3) If I do use everything described above, including the table on a MySQL DB, what are some things I could do to optimize it? I thought about storing the table in memory, but I don't like the idea of losing its contents whenever the server crashes or is restarted. The closest thing I can think of would be to have a standard InnoDB table where writes and updates are done, and another, 1:1 mirror memory table where reads are performed. Using triggers it should be doable to have the memory table mirror everything, but on the other hand it does sound like a pain in the ass to maintain (fubar situations can easily happen if some reason the tables get desynchronized).

Comment: The insane part is spawning child processes in an incredible rate, IMHO.

Comment: Could be, these child processes are meant to be short-lived though, that is, they do one thing quickly and then they die.

Comment: Well, what if they don't? I think it's best to impose some limit on the number of concurrent worker programs. And: if they are effectively competing for the same resources (which I presume they do), allowing more processes would only slow things down.

Comment: True, you raise a valid point. Perhaps the daemon should check how many workers are on it and when they finish, maybe I should just use an actual queue system within the daemon like gearman to dispatch the due events consistently. Of course I could have the work done on the actual daemon, but well it's PHP and I was concerned leaks would accumulate fast that way.

Comment: Actually on the other hand a queue system has to run indefinitely anyway to catch the jobs, so I'm not sure if it would be any better than simply running the tasks directly in the daemon itself...

Comment: The simplest way: let the child-process eat from the queue, one by one, and delete the entry after subtask completion. Exit once the queue is empty (or after handling xxx request). For the master-process: if there is no worker process: start one; sleep for a sane amount of time. If you *reaaly* want more than one child process, things will get complex. (the workers all eat from the same worklist, but can only delete from it once they are done)

Comment: Makes sense, I'll give that a try, thanks. Other than that, do you think the server will be able to handle it if the daemon hits the database every tenth of a second? assuming a relatively robust machine, I'm just not sure if it is feasible at all.